# Is it possible to import multiple contracts inside a remix test and pass an ERC20 address?

Tags: solidity, remix, unittesting, remix-tests

I want to run unit tests in remix where I have 2 contracts Token A (AUSDC) that will be exchanged for Token B (AToken)

However, during the imports, I am shown the ff: error

```
import "../contracts/1_AUSDC.sol";
import "../contracts/2_AToken.sol";


DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
--> tests/2_AToken_test.sol:7:1:
|
7 | import "../contracts/2_AToken.sol";
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: The previous declaration is here:
--> contracts/1_AUSDC.sol:4:1:
|
4 | interface IERC20 {
| ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

The contracts are as follows

AUSDC

```
interface IERC20 {
...
}

contract AUSDC is IERC20 {
//my logic
}
```

AToken

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
contract AToken is IERC20 {
constructor(IERC20 ausdcAddress){}
}
```

I am already able to run unit tests on AUSDC but not on AToken because

1. Imports are showing errors
2. I am not aware how to pass an ERC20 address to the test contract.

Appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you

Comment: `SafeERC20` imported in AToken uses the OpenZeppelin definition `IERC20` which seems to conflict with your own from `AUSDC`.  Is there any reason that you are using two different `IERC20` definitions ?

Comment: Hi, the first one was an old contract I played around with, then I wanted to switch to OpenZeppelin. I just added the old IERC interface to the second one but it still shows me the same error.